# How to transfer all the contents in one azure data lake container to another using databricks?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have a container called test-container, and I'd like to move all the files and folders in test-container over to test2-container. How can I do this in a databricks notebook using pyspark?

Comment: We can't help you design the code. You can achieve that with copy active directly. Do you think about that or insist using notebook？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to mount both containers, assuming that containers are not public, (/ if it the root folder) then use dbfs cli to move files/folders between the mount points created before.

dbfs mv /mnt/folder1 /mnt/folder2.

If you change the access level of the containers to "Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs)", you should be able to move files directly without even creating mounts.

In Databricks notebook the code should be something like this -

%fs
mv /mnt/folder1 /mnt/folder2

Comment: I have the containers mounted, I was wondering more so if it is possible with code, preferably pyspark to move all the files and folders in 1 mounted container to another. I understand I can just copy and paste in azure storage explorer but was wanting to see if it is possible to do so with python spark.

Comment: won't this work with a databricks notebook? %fs mv /mnt/folder1 /mnt/folder2

Comment: wow I can't believe it was this easy to do this. That worked perfectly. Thank you so much!